# How to recover a previous file version in perforce branch?

Tags: perforce

I have deleted a file from a perforce branch and I am trying to recover it. I thought of syncing to its previous version and resubmitting it. Is it the better way to do and how?

P.S: Using command line

Answer (score 2):

You've got it.

```
p4 sync file#version
p4 add file
p4 submit
```

Another option (only available with server versions after ~2013):

```
p4 copy file#version file
p4 submit
```

Another other option (only available with server versions after ~2016):

```
p4 undo file#head
p4 submit
```

Any of these ways you do it, the history will record that the new version came from the older one (you'll see "file#4 add from file#2" or something along those lines), and that will do things like connect up the history in Revision Graph and allow merge operations to find a common base.